# Div width has a gap

Tags: html, css

So I am writing my hero section again because I want to add some animations to it.
now I have noticed that there is a small "gap" as you can see in the image below:
[image: Look at the red circle]

Now, is there anyway to fix it? I'm a bit lost

```css
.hero-section {
    height: 100vh;
    size: cover;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    
}

.hero-section > .hero-content > .top-heading {
    background-color: rgba(0, 188, 203, 0.7);
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.hero-section > .hero-content > .bottom-heading {
    background-color: rgba(0, 188, 203, 0.7);
    margin-top: 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
            <div className="hero-section" id="hero-section">
                    <div className="hero-content">
                        <div className="top-heading">
                            <h1>Are you looking for an apartment in Israel?</h1>
                        </div>
                        <div className="bottom-heading">
                            <h1>Do you need help finding a buyer or a seller?</h1>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Are you referring to the gap between the lines of text (or the line-height)?

Comment: In HTML is `class`, not `className`

Comment: @j08691 he is proberly using soemthing like django

Comment: Do you want the two lines left justified, or centered? Do you want the green backgrounds to be the same width as each other, or to be the width of the text?

Comment: @tacoshy could be, which is why I prefaced my comment with "In HTML"

Answer (score 0):

Your text sections are children of the flexbox, so they don't take on the `justify-content:center` style rule. To fix this you can just give `.top-heading` and `.bottom-heading` a `text-align:center` rule.

```css
.hero-section {
  height: 100vh;
  size: cover;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.top-heading, .bottom-heading {
  background-color: rgba(0, 188, 203, 0.7);
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align:center;
}

.bottom-heading {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="hero-section" id="hero-section">
  <div class="hero-content">
    <div class="top-heading">
      <h1>Are you looking for an apartment in Israel?</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom-heading">
      <h1>Do you need help finding a buyer or a seller?</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey, this havent fixed my issue, now its just centered between the gaps...

Answer (score 0):

The `h1` tags are block by default so they expand horizontally. By setting them to display `inline`, you're able to have them centered and a background without a gap:

```css
.hero-section {
    height: 100vh;
    size: cover;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.hero-section > .hero-content > .top-heading {
    text-align: center;
}

.hero-section > .hero-content > .bottom-heading {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.hero-section > .hero-content > .top-heading > .heading,
.hero-section > .hero-content > .bottom-heading > .heading {
    background-color: rgba(0, 188, 203, 0.7);
    border-radius: 5px;
    display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div class="hero-section" id="hero-section">
                    <div class="hero-content">
                        <div class="top-heading">
                            <h1 class="heading">Are you looking for an apartment in Israel?</h1>
                        </div>
                        <div class="bottom-heading">
                            <h1 class="heading">Do you need help finding a buyer or a seller?</h1>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.hero-section {
    height: 100vh;
    size: cover;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    
}

.hero-section > .hero-content > .top-heading {
    background-color: rgba(0, 188, 203, 0.7);
    border-radius: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.hero-section > .hero-content > .bottom-heading {
    background-color: rgba(0, 188, 203, 0.7);
    margin-top: 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.top-heading h1, .bottom-heading h1{
   display: inline;
   margin: 0;
   font-size: 1.9em;
}
```

```html
            <div class="hero-section" id="hero-section">
                    <div class="hero-content">
                        <div class="top-heading">
                            <h1>Are you looking for an apartment in Israel?</h1>
                        </div>
                        <div class="bottom-heading">
                            <h1>Do you need help finding a buyer or a seller?</h1>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Heading tags are **block element** and they **take 100% width**. You have to give it css that limits its width according to its content *i.e*

```
h1{display:inline-block}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this haven't fixed the gap...

Comment: @NoamAzoulay may be it is taking margin from top and bottom so you should also use margin:0px; in the above code